# pyspark - TypeError: 'Price' object is not iterable

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I'm getting TypeError when i try to convert RDD of Price object to `Pair RDD`.

**Sample code:**

```
priceRDD = pppConformInDF.rdd.map(lambda row: Price(row.vyge_id, row.strm_typ_cd, row.sfb_nm, row.txn_dt, row.vfa_extra_am, '2'))
priceKeyValueRDD = priceRDD.map(lambda price: (",".join([price.vyge_id, price.strm_typ_cd, price.sfb_nm]), list(price)))
```

How do i convert the RDD of Price object to Key value RDD, the value is the Price object and Key is combination of some of the fields in Price object.

**Error log:**

```
    priceKeyValueRDD = priceRDD.map(lambda price: (",".join([price.vyge_id, price.strm_typ_cd, price.sfb_nm]), list(price)))
TypeError: 'Price' object is not iterable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your got is because of `list(price)` operation, as price cannot convert to a list.

Just remove `list`, then use `groupByKey()` to aggregate prices with the same key into a list.

```
priceRDD = pppConformInDF.rdd.map(lambda row: Price(row.vyge_id, row.strm_typ_cd, row.sfb_nm, row.txn_dt, row.vfa_extra_am, '2'))
priceKeyValueRDD = priceRDD.map(lambda price: (",".join([price.vyge_id, price.strm_typ_cd, price.sfb_nm]), price))
priceGroupedRDD = priceKeyValueRDD.groupByKey() # returns something like [(key->iterable of prices)]
```

Comment: the result is coming as tuple, and the value is Price object not list of Price.. am i missing something?

Comment: If you apply `map` function to `priceGroupedRDD`, each row is indeed a tuple `(key, iterable of prices)`.

Comment: For example getting length of list, `priceGroupedRDD.map(lambda x : (x[0], len(x[1])))`

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.groupByKey